# java - Calling specific servlet based on url request?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I'm pretty new to JSP, Servlet and Tomcat. If I point multiple domains to the IP adress of a server, is there a way I can call the relevant Servlet programmically, based on which domain has been requested?

Maybe there something I can do in web.xml?

Sorry for my lack of knowledge - I'm just getting started:(

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Comment: see this http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP host header will tell you which domain the client requested.

The way to obtain this via the Servlet API is:

```
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getHeader("host");
```

Comment: Oh cool, so I'd just set up a default servlet and then process the domain in the doGet/doPost of the Servlet? (then presumeably forward the response to the specific website's Servlet/main JSP page?)

Comment: That would work. If each site has it's own servlet(s) (that could be packaged in a separate WAR) , then virtual hosting is also an option.

Comment: Also, is this a practical way to host multiple domains and their relevant sites on one tomcat server?

Comment: I would say no. I'd use virtual hosting for that unless the sites are 99.9% the same with minor differences then I'd check the host header at the few points where a per domain response was required.

Comment: Cool thanks. Could you send me a link on setting up virtual hosts please?:)

Comment: Also, why would this not be a suitable option? Are there any discussions/articles about virtual hosts vs this type of forwarding? Would you say, for example, a method lie this would be more suited to subdomains?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to have the same web application respond to multiple domains, you might look at having a dispatcher servlet or dispatcher filter. Frameworks like Struts 2 and Spring MVC use these concepts to route requests to the appropriate servlet. With a dispatcher servlet, you can use whatever conditions you want (in your case, hostname) to route to the approriate servlet.

If you are instead looking to have *separate* web applications respond to the different hostnames and/or IP addresses (commonly referred to as virtual hosting), then you might want to look at [Tomcat virtual hosting](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html). This is also commonly handled by putting a web server like Apache or IIS in front of Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Redirect the request to the correct servlet using "RequestDispatcher"

Answer (score -2):

use something like:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
 throws IOException {

        // Get client's IP address
        String ipAddress = req.getRemoteAddr(); // ip 

        // Get client's hostname
        String hostname = req.getRemoteHost(); // hostname
    }
```

Comment: The OP wanted the Host header, not the client IP address.